# Use a proposition to prove another proposition

Tags: logic, proof-verification

I'd like to ask for help with an exercise from Solow - How to Read and Do Proofs(3.16). I've tried to get through it but I can't make the proper connection between the two properties. I figured that $b\ge|2a|$  guarantees  that $b^2-4a^2 \ge 0$ but other than that I am stuck. Thanks.

Suppose you have already proved the proposition: 
If a and b are nonnegative real numbers, then $(a+b)/2 \ge \sqrt{ab}$.

a. Explain precisely how this proposition could be used to prove that if a and b are real numbers satisfying the property that $b \ge 2|a|$, then $b \ge \sqrt{b^2 - 4a^2}$.
Be careful how you match up notation.

Edit: Corrected a mistake.

Comment: Examine what you have written. $b\geq 2a$ is definitely not the same thing as $b\geq 2|a|$.

Comment: Note that $b^2-4a^2=(b-2a)(b+2a)$. The two factors here are both nonnegative if and only if $b\geq 2a$.

Comment: That should be "if and only if $b\geq2|a|$". I am unable to edit the previous comment, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, $b\ge 2a\Rightarrow b^2\ge 4a^2$ is not true. It's true if $b\ge 2a\ge 0.$

You can do with $b\ge 2|a|$ as the followings :

Since $b\ge 2|a|\ge 0$, we have $b+2|a|\ge 0$ and $b-2|a|\ge 0$. Then by the proposition, we have
$$\frac{(b+2|a|)+(b-2|a|)}{2}\ge\sqrt{(b+2|a|)(b-2|a|)}\iff b\ge\sqrt {b^2-4a^2}$$
as desired. Here, note that $|a|^2=a^2$.